# How to Create New Mesh From Animation Frame?

Tags: animation, armature

How to create new mesh from animation frame?

I've got an object that is deformed by an armature and I want to make a copy of the deformed mesh at a specific frame.

Answer (score 2):

The process is deceptively easy.

1. Duplicate the mesh.
2. Go to the frame you want.
3. Apply your modifiers, the Armature modifier is the most important one in this instance.

Congratulations, you now have a static deformed mesh at the frame of your choosing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. Answering your own question is possible and even encouraged, as long as it done respecting the site structure. Maybe add a short description of the steps accompanied by a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)